# Why `insertUI` is not working as an alternative for module UI?

Tags: r, shiny

I have tried to use `insertUI` as an alternative for explicitly using module UI in the UI part of Shiny app, but without the success. How should I use `insertUI` in my example to get the desired effect, i.e. to be able to display `modalDialog`?

**This doesn't work** (using `insertUI` instead of explicitly using module in `UI` part of app):

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

modUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  key_pressed <- ns("key_pressed")
  js <- glue::glue_safe('
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {{
     Shiny.setInputValue("{key_pressed}", e.key, {{priority: "event"}});
    }});
  ')
  singleton(tags$script(htmltools::HTML(js)))
}

modServer <- function(keyEvent = "F1",
                                  id) {
  
  insertUI("head", "beforeEnd", modUI("test"), immediate = TRUE)
  
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      observe({
        req(input$key_pressed == keyEvent)
        showModal(modalDialog())
      }) %>% 
        bindEvent(input$key_pressed)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  #modUI("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  modServer(id = "test")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**This works** (using module explicitly in the `UI` part of app):

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

modUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  key_pressed <- ns("key_pressed")
  js <- glue::glue_safe('
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {{
     Shiny.setInputValue("{key_pressed}", e.key, {{priority: "event"}});
    }});
  ')
  singleton(tags$script(htmltools::HTML(js)))
}

modServer <- function(keyEvent = "F1",
                                  id) {
  
  #insertUI("head", "beforeEnd", modUI("test"), immediate = TRUE)
  
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      observe({
        req(input$key_pressed == keyEvent)
        showModal(modalDialog())
      }) %>% 
        bindEvent(input$key_pressed)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  modUI("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  modServer(id = "test")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code above adds JS code to add keydown listener - **`modalDialog` will be displayed after pressing `F1`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A search in the Shiny GitHub repository reveals that [this is an open issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1545) with Shiny: inserted `script` tags aren't executed unless wrapped in `tags$head()`. So, meanwhile, you could wrap the script tag in your module UI in `tags$head()` to get this to work:

```r
script <- tags$script(htmltools::HTML(js))
singleton(tags$head(script))
```